# Variable defined inside of function carries over when function is called multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scoping

This is in python.

So, I have defined a function of the sort:

```
def function(var1, var2 = [[], 0]):
    # some code that changes both var1 and var2
    return (var2, var1)
```

Then, I made a for loop:

```
for x in range(10):
    print(function(x))
```

I make a couple changes to `var2` inside of the function. The issue that I am having is that the changes happened inside of `var2` carry over for each next iteration in the for loop involving `x`. I don't understand why it does so. The way I've fixed it is calling this instead:

```
for x in range(10):
    print(function(x, [[], 0]))
```

However, I don't want to have to do this (to specify each time that var2 is `[[], 0]`).

Also, if that may help, the function is recursive. It runs fine, just that `var2` carries over.

How can I prevent this for happening?

Comment: You have a mutable argument default `var2=[[], 0]`. The default will only be instantiated once. If you chance it it will be changed in the next call as well. To be safe use non-mutable default values like tuples.

Comment: Please show proper code. what changes you have done to var2 inside the function

Comment: You mutate the list in-place and return it. Usually one does one or the other. Is mutating in place mandatory for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python creates a function's default parameters once when the code is first compiled and uses that object whenever a default is needed. One consequence is that if the parameter is mutable, like a list, any changes to it are seen in all future calls. One solution is to use a different value as a default and use it to create the default dynamically

```
def function(var1, var2=None):
    if var2 is None:
        var2 = [[], 0]
    # some code that changes both var1 and var2
    return (var2, var1)
```

Another option is to stop mutating the list in place, but return a copy instead.

```
from copy import deepcopy

def function(var1, var2=[[], 0]):
    var1 = deepcopy(var1)
    var2 = deepcopy(var2)
    # some code that changes both var1 and var2
    return (var2, var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How can I prevent this for happening? use `tuple` instead of `list` `var2=((), 0)`.

explanation: The `list` specified as default argument `var2` is **stored once and fetched every time** the function is called, unless you specify a different argument as var2. So when that list is modified, next time it is fetched, it carries the modifications. that is why using `list` as default argument is a bad practice use `tuple` instead, because `tuple` is *immutable*.

Comment: That changes the problem to `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment` but doesn't get rid of the problem completely.